# Git workflow, TortoiseGit, pulling and pushing

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm a bit new to Git environment, but I had quite a lot of SVN experiences so far, so I kinda know how things work, or at least the general idea behind it.

That being said I do have some issues with Git.

I've created a copy of git repository on my disk, changed some files, added some files and committed+pushed changes to the repository.

After that Push command goes away and I can only commit new changes, I also get tons of files that I never changed, never really opened before that I need to commit, even if I haven't worked on them.

So I tried deleting the whole git directory, created another copy of repository and same thing happens - I make some changes, commit and push them and then the Push option disappears and I get tons of files to commit I have never worked on, so I can't push any legitimate changes to the repository anymore and even if I had the option I get various files to commit, that I did not change.

I'm using TortoiseGit via context menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of TortoiseGit do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having file permission issues, try the following command within your local repo...

git config -e

then change filemode option to false. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: I assume then TortoiseGit does a bad job at displaying operation errors.